# Where did the energy released due to gravitational binding energy of the Earth go?

Tags: geophysics, earth-history, geothermal-heat, planetary-formation

The gravitational binding energy of the Earth is $2×10^{32}  J $, so the same amount of energy must have been released during the Earth's history.

According to [this](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=rf419f-p4D8C&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=earth%20internal%20energy%201031&source=bl&ots=vOBvhyjgZu&sig=Fr63wbCRm-LdSSFFXilKoMplc9M&hl=ar&sa=X&ei=fEuLVPrDNIb9Uo_MgpAB&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=earth%20internal%20energy%201031&f=false) and [this](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=qyN6_83vz2MC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=earth%20energy%201031&source=bl&ots=fFzkC7Jl2r&sig=ey04DuzETjpfWDPHFRnmaEs4ew4&hl=ar&sa=X&ei=mkuLVOSaJ4K0UYPfgqgF&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=earth%20energy%201031&f=false), the current internal energy of the Earth is ~ $1.5×10^{31} J$, and according to [this](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=4ey5BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=earth%20internal%20energy%201031&source=bl&ots=Zsqn2sk7sI&sig=pKqC0LMcAHHJ7QpcjLxH0HW7oSM&hl=ar&sa=X&ei=LUWLVP-NBcKvU4Lbg5AM&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=earth%20internal%20energy%201031&f=false) source, the amount of heat loss due to outward radiation by the Earth during the entire lifetime of the planet is about $0.45×10^{31}  J $.

So, by adding those two numbers we get the Earth internal energy + energy radiated = ~ $2×10^{31}  J $, which is an order of magnitude less than what we should expect. 
We are also ignoring the fact that 50-90% of the current internal energy of the Earth is due to radioactive decay. So where did the rest of the energy go ?

Comment: Cross posted and answered here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/152979/where-did-the-energy-released-due-to-gravitational-binding-energy-of-the-earth-g

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions. Your question on physics.se already has answers. Closing for cross-posting.